# Changing the footer of DataTables

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm trying to change the footer of dataTables to be a custom defined one. Instead of `"Showing x to y of z entries."` I want it to show `"Showing x to y of (my own value) entries."` DataTables bases the entry count off of the number of rows in the table, but I want it to show a count of entries in a database.

```
    $('#' + table_name).dataTable({
      "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "Showing blah to blah of my_own_number entries."
      }
    });
```

Though, I'm getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'aaSorting' of null`

Instead of using any variables in the message, I'm just trying to change the message for now to something like "hello new footer." instead of "Showing...entries" but even using a simple message like this results in the same error.

Comment: The error seems to be unrelated to the code sample posted.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
"sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of " + my_own_number + " entries."
```